# Selecting all data from a table and a column from another table

Tags: sql, join, select

The query:

```
SELECT A.*, B.category 
FROM table1 A 
LEFT JOIN table2 B 
WHERE B.code = A.code;
```

I have a query here, but I know that it it is not working the way I want to.

I have two table and I want to select all the data from the first table and a column in the second table. The query I created have errors and I cannot think another way to have the output that I want.

The data:

[image: data]

The expected output:

[image: expected output]

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.*, B.category 
FROM table1 A 
LEFT JOIN table2 B 
ON B.code = A.code;
```

Instead of WHERE, it's ON